# Get unique elements from R dataframe for sequencing data

Tags: r

I am working on some data transformations on sequencing data in R Studio. I would like to get unique channels from  my sequencing data. Here is an example -

```
sequence = c("a > b", "b > c > a > d", "f")
success = c(0,1,0)

df = data.frame(sequence,success)
df

> df
       sequence success
1         a > b   0
2 b > c > a > d   1
3             f   0
```

I would like to get all the unique channels in this case. So my output should look like -

```
> unique_channels
a
b
c
d
f
```

Note that the separator in my `df$sequence` is fixed to be `>`

Answer (score 4):

If the separator is fixed, then you just need to split the strings and count the unique elements:

```
unique_channels <- unique(unlist(strsplit(sequence, ' > ')))
```

Comment: that works, thank you for the answer. But what is the data type of the `unique_channels` variable ? Is it still a dataframe ? If not, can I convert it ?

Comment: `unique_channels` will be a character vector. You can create a data.frame from it just by calling `data.frame(unique_channels)`

Comment: thank you for the help. It certainly saved a lot of time. I especially liked the one liner for finding unique elements.

Comment: @Regressor make sure you use `data.frame(unique_channels,stringsAsFactors=F)`.